# Local abstract class gives warning C4101

Tags: visual-c++, warnings

I have to deal with code that can be reduced as follows:

```
void  main ()
{
    class MyBase
    {
    public:
        virtual void  MyFunc () = 0;
    };

    class MyClass : public MyBase
    {
    public:
        virtual void  MyFunc () {}
    };

    MyClass  x;
}
```

When compiling under Visual-C++ 2010 with `cl /nologo /Wall text.cxx', I get the following warning:

```
test.cxx(7) : warning C4101: 'main::MyBase::MyFunc' : unreferenced local variable
```

I want to keep `MyBase` in place if possible (because it is deep down inside the code hierarchy).

Is there a way to 'fix' the code in place (other than using `#pragma` to ignore the warning)? Or is it bad practice to have a local abstract class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here the warning is about unused `x`. Does it change if you for example call `x.MyFunc()` ?